# Is it possible to generate source based on syntax tree generated by another generator?

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators

For example, we have Pure.DI library that generates fast DI compositions. Is it possible to create generator that creates input for Pure.DI generator(based on some attributes or another kind of metainformation) and then make sure that Pure.DI generates its internal code based on output of our generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's impossible for roslyn source generators.

> Each generator will see the same input compilation, with no access to
> files created by other source generators.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md).

But I believe you can achieve that by running custom exe, batch, or even T4-based generator in pre-build action of msbuild or csproj file.

Comment: Thanks for answer... Unfortunately :(